# determine the convergence of $x_n=(\frac{5\sum_{k=1}^nk^4}{n^5})^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I want to determine the limit of that succession, for which I did the following

like $\sum^n_{k=1} k^4 = \frac{n (n + 1) (2 n + 1) (3 n^2 + 3 n - 1)}{30}$, then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{5\sum_{k=1}^nk^4}{n^5})^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{5}{5n}\frac{n(n+1)}{n}\frac{(2n+1)}{2n}\frac{(3n^2+3n-1)}{3n^2})^n=\Big(1+\frac1n\Big)^n\Big(1+\frac{1}{2n}\Big)^n\Big(1+\frac{1}{n}\big(1-\frac{1}{3n}\big)\Big)^n$$

From where
$lim_{n\to\infty}\Big(1+\frac1n\Big)^n=e, lim_{n\to\infty}\Big(1+\frac{1}{2n}\Big)^n=\sqrt[]{e}, lim_{n\to\infty}\Big(1+\frac{1}{n}\big(1-\frac{1}{3n}\big)\Big)^n=e$

Thus $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{5\sum_{k=1}^nk^4}{n^5})^n=e^2\sqrt[]{e}$$

Is the above correct, any help?

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: For the quick answer you can also use the Euler–Maclaurin formula:
$\sum_{k=1}^nf(k)=\int_0^nf(x)dx+\frac{1}{2}(f(n)+f(1)) +...$

In your case $5\sum_{k=1}^nk^4=5\int_0^nx^4dx+\frac{5}{2}n^4+O(n^3)=n^5+\frac{5}{2}n^4+O(n^3)$
$\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big(\frac{n^5+\frac{5}{2}n^4+O(n^3)}{n^5}\Big)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big(1+\frac{5}{2n}\Big)^n=e^\frac{5}{2}$